# How to do I groupby, count and then plot a bar chart in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `Pandas` dataframe that looks like the following.

```
year  month  class
----  -----  -----
2015  1      1
2015  1      1
2015  1      2
2015  1      2
...
```

I want to be able to create 2 bar chart series of of this data on one plot. If I can do a `groupby`, `count` and end up with a `data frame` then I am thinking I can just do a simple `dataframe.plot.barh`.

What I have tried is the following code.

```
x = df.groupby(['year', 'month', 'class'])['class'].count()
```

What `x` ends up being is a `Series`. So then I do the following to get a `DataFrame`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
```

Which gets me pretty close. The data ends up looking like the following.

```
                       clazz
year month clazz        
2015 1     1            2
     2     1           15
     2     2           45
```

But when I do a bar plot `df.plot.bar()`, I only see one series. The output desired is simply in one series, from 2015-01 to 2019-12, how many times did `class` 1 occur per month? And then another series, from 2015-01 to 2019-12, how many times did `class` 2 occur per month?

Any ideas on how to manipulate the data to be in this way?

Comment: You can use .reset_index() to your x DataFrame to have a full DataFrame and then use matplotlib easily.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A `groupby`-`unstack` should do the trick:

**Data**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[2015, 1, 1],
                    [2015, 1, 1],
                    [2015, 1, 2],
                    [2015, 1, 2],
                    [2015, 1, 2],
                    [2015, 2, 1],
                    [2015, 2, 1],
                    [2015, 2, 1],
                    [2015, 2, 2],
                    [2015, 2, 2]], columns = ['year', 'month', 'class'])
```

**Solution**

```
df_gb = df.groupby(['year', 'month', 'class']).size().unstack(level=2)
```

**Output**

```
df_gb.plot(kind = 'bar')
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

We can also use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df.pivot_table(index=['year','month'],columns='class',aggfunc='size').plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

---

or

```
df.pivot_table(index='class',columns=['year','month'],aggfunc='size').plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]